# Como focar em uma DIV específica e desfocar o restante

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Existe alguma biblioteca Javascript/Jquery que de um `target`delimitando uma área em uma `DIV` específica e desfoque no restante ?

Exemplo

Adicionei um novo item ao menu e assim que carregasse a tela desse um foco em cima e desfocasse o restante para ficar em evidência ?

**Obs: Acredito que terá que trabalhar com coordenadas pois queria ter a liberdade de colocar esse target em qualquer lugar da tela**

Foto hipotética:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Só uma dúvida, quando vc fala "desfocar" vc quer que o resto do menu fique com um efeito de "embaçado" tipo desfocado mesmo, ou vc quer que o item quando clicado aparece essa borda vermelha?

Comment: @hugocsl exatamente isso, assim que carregar a tela, ele vai desfocar (embaçado) a pagina inteira e apenas deixar e evidência o novo item, com esse borda/target delimitando ele ai caso seja clicado em qualquer lugar essa estilização suma ... 

isso é para 'mostrar' novas funcionalidades, pra ajudar operadores que são 'visuais'

Comment: `border: 10px solid red`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz esse modelo só com CSS, usando um pouco de JS vc consegue fazer do jeito que quer, basta adaptar pra sua situação ai.

O ideia e colocar no elemento que engloba todo o conteúdo um `filter:blur()`, e quando vc clicar no *btn* vc remove o filter do *container* que tem o restante do conteúdo.

Esse é apenas um exemplo, eu usei `label + input` para fazer a dinâmica da coisa ok

```css
#btn {
  display: none;
}
#btn:checked + .holder .fake {
  display: none;
}
#btn:checked ~ .blur {
  filter: blur(0);
}
.holder {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.btn {
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.blur {
  filter: blur(6px);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="btn">

<div class="holder">
  <label class="btn">btn</label>
  <label class="btn fake" for="btn">btn</label>
</div>  
<div class="blur">
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium maiores vero asperiores quisquam assumenda laudantium quidem esse dolores. Voluptatem velit et officia iste. Autem corrupti, asperiores in maxime alias explicabo.</p>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/100" alt="">
  <p>Possimus quo alias veniam! Obcaecati ea ipsam unde, sit dolorum architecto, deserunt in aperiam recusandae neque qui officia minus provident. Similique adipisci recusandae facere reiciendis cupiditate repellat, dolores nisi maxime?</p>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/100" alt="">
  <p>Porro, harum repudiandae dolores praesentium ducimus pariatur voluptate, nihil doloremque ratione obcaecati inventore laboriosam veritatis. Minima dolore molestiae tempore repellendus consequatur quisquam voluptates, incidunt repellat accusantium eaque? Magni, totam! Animi.</p>
  <p>Sunt delectus odit facere impedit officiis, ea rerum nobis nesciunt iure atque quisquam, maiores, tempore earum suscipit eaque nihil nostrum. Nihil quaerat laborum adipisci autem veritatis vero recusandae reiciendis voluptatem!</p>
  <p>Sequi enim commodi culpa impedit quos nostrum repudiandae consequatur ullam. Quaerat necessitatibus repellat odio, velit eos beatae iste eaque sed quas, consequuntur doloremque iure voluptate totam asperiores culpa. Perferendis, odio.</p>
  <p>Aspernatur eius rerum harum necessitatibus natus repellendus sit optio perspiciatis voluptatum, consectetur corporis magnam adipisci debitis, voluptatem ea aliquam quaerat explicabo. Sit atque quas tempore assumenda tempora nam culpa non?</p>
  <p>Sed, dolor architecto. Error voluptate exercitationem beatae accusamus id voluptatum modi architecto nemo harum eveniet ex totam, blanditiis dolorum deleniti, est necessitatibus? Consequatur blanditiis nulla quod pariatur sed adipisci nisi?</p>
  <p>Itaque laudantium alias, vel placeat cupiditate omnis, possimus aut, corrupti at suscipit nostrum veritatis fuga consequuntur aliquid reiciendis laboriosam! Beatae, et ratione atque neque assumenda sunt ut laborum laboriosam ad!</p>
  <p>Amet autem omnis atque provident facere praesentium sint, consequuntur illum adipisci libero assumenda vero natus quis reiciendis hic alias iure nemo, quaerat, sequi ex! Consequuntur voluptates excepturi tempore esse repellendus.</p>
  <p>Sapiente consequuntur recusandae soluta debitis sequi totam ratione obcaecati veritatis laborum deserunt, incidunt quae quia nostrum harum illum quaerat ipsum a deleniti vel voluptatibus vitae! Commodi rerum reiciendis quas magni?</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode trabalhar com a propriedade `position` e `z-index` do CSS... Ao clicar no elemento desejado você adiciona uma div com 100% com o fundo desejado e define o `position` e o `z-index` acima desta div criada para sobrepor o restante do conteúdo.

Comment: Isso ajuda em 70% do problema. Mas a questão é que eu preciso trabalhar com coordenadas para ter a liberdade de jogar esse target em qualquer lugar da página, e não tem que ser no clique, iria ser ao carregar a página.

Comment: Você não pode jogar esse target através de um identificador?